# Find a sequence converging to $\{1/k\}^{\infty}_{k=1}$ in $l^2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

Let $s=\{1/k\}^{\infty}_{k=1}$. Find a sequence $\{s_n\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ of points in $l^2$ such that each $s_n$ is distinct from $s$ and such that $\{s_n\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ converges to $s$ in $l^2$.

This is a problem from Goldberg. Exercise 4.3, 3. I don't understand the question. How can I find a sequence that converges to another sequence? Is $s$ the limit of $\{1/k\}$ or it is the variable assigned to the sequence itself? If it is the limit then it can be worked out

Comment: Recall that $l^2$ is the space of all square summable *sequences*, i.e. the elements of $l^2$ are sequences, so you need to find a sequence of sequences that converges to the sequence $\{1/k\}_{k=1}^\infty$.

Comment: @sobi Thanks! now I understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Recall that [$l^2$ is the normed space of all square summable sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space#%E2%84%93p_spaces) $s$, such that
$$\|s\|^2_2=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}s(k)^2<+\infty.$$
Let $s_n(k):=\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{nk}$ (also $s_n(k):=\frac{a_n}{k}$ with $a_n\to 1$  will work), then  $\{s_n(k)\}_{k\geq1}\in l^2$ for each $n\geq 1$. Now consider the limit of
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\|s_n-s\|^2_2=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(s_n(k)-\frac{1}{k}\right)^2$$
and show that it is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $s_n = \left(1, \frac12, \ldots, \frac1n, 0, 0, \ldots\right) \in \ell^2$. We have

$$\|s - s_n\|_2^2 = \left\|\left(0, , \ldots, 0, \frac1{n+1}, \frac1{n+2}, \ldots\right)\right\|_2^2 = \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac1{k^2} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$$

because $\sum \frac1{k^2}$ is a convergent series. Therefore $(s_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $s$ in $\ell^2$.

Answer (score 0):

@RobertZ was much quicker than me, but here is another example in case you need it. Put
$$ s_n = \left\{\frac{1}{k+\frac{1}{n}}\right\}_{k=1}^\infty. $$
Then $s_n \in l^2$ for each $n \geq 1$ by comparison with $\sum 1/k^2,$ i.e.
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{k+\frac{1}{n}}\right)^2 \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} < \infty, $$
and $s_n \to s$ in $l^2$ since
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{k+\frac{1}{n}}-\frac{1}{k} \right)^2
=  \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{\left(k+\frac{1}{n}\right)k}\right)^2
\leq \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^4} \to 0, \text{ as } n\to \infty, $$
since the last sum is bounded.